# Why I'm getting error for some cases, though I'm getting correct outputs for manually entered values?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve a problem after submitting I'm getting runtime error(SIGABRT) for test cases; this is my first time when I encountered with this error: `SIGABRT`, I can't understand why this error is occurring?

I am providing question and input-output for reference:

A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {
        std::string text;
        std::cin >> text;

        int count = text.size();

        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            std::string s, res;

            for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
            {
                s += text[i];
            }

            res = s;
            reverse(res.begin(), res.end());

            long long val1 = std::stoll(s + res);
            long long val2 = std::stoll(text);
            long long val3 = std::stoll(s);

            if (val1 <= val2)
            {
                val3 = val3 + 1;

                std::string s = std::to_string(val3);
                reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

                std::cout << val3 << s << '\n';
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << s + res << '\n';
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (count % 2 != 0)
        {
            long long flag1 = std::stoll(text);
            std::string s1, s2;

            for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
            {
                text[count - 1 - i] = text[i];

                s1 += text[i];
            }

            s2 = s1;
            s1 += text[(count / 2)];

            long long flag2 = std::stoll(text);
            long long flag3 = std::stoll(s1);

            if (flag2 <= flag1)
            {
                flag3 = flag3 + 1;

                if (text[count / 2] == '9')
                {
                    int val = flag3 / 10;
                    std::string s = std::to_string(val);

                    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

                    std::cout << flag3 << s << '\n';
                }
                else
                {
                    reverse(s2.begin(), s2.end());

                    std::cout << flag3 << s2 << '\n';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << flag2 << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

**Inputs:**

```
4
808
2133
55555555555555
99999999999999
```

**Outputs:**

```
818
2222
55555566555555
1000000000000001
```

Comment: Do you submit your code to some code evaluation website? It's probably get aborted while exceeding it's run time limit. Specify where do you submit to might help

Comment: Depending on your platform, a number with 1000000 digits may not entirely fit within a `long long`.

Comment: @LouisGo Actually this problem is from SPOJ practice site, Link: https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

Comment: No numeric conversions should be required for this task. You effectively need a semi-intelligent string-as-number set of functions. No general platform is going to have native numeric types sporting million-digit values.